# Resolve Variable Scope Problem with a Nuxt and serverMiddleware (Node API)

Tags: node.js, api, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am using Nuxt. I'm trying to work with Zoom's API that insists on me doing server-side calls. So I made a serverMiddleware that looks like this:

```sh
require('dotenv').config
const https = require('https')
const querystring = require('querystring')

export default function(req, res){
    if (req.method === 'GET'){
        const url = new URL(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`)

        let host = 'zoom.us'
        let tail = '/oauth/token?'
        let query = querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: url.searchParams.get('code'),
            redirect_uri: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL
        })
        
        let data = process.env.NUXT_ENV_ZOOM_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.NUXT_ENV_ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET
        let newData = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')
        let b64string = newData.toString('base64')

        function getZoomAccessToken(){
            const options = {
                hostname: host,
                path: tail + query,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64string
                }
            }
            return https.request(options, response => {
                let data = ''
                response.on('data', (chunk) => { 
                    data += chunk.toString()
                })
            
                response.on('end', () => { 
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data)); 
                })
            })
            .on('error', (error) => { 
                console.log('An error', error)
            })
            .end()  
        }
        
        let body = getZoomAccessToken()
        console.log(body)
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        res.end(body)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm having trouble trying to get data from the `https.request` callback. How do I make sure that I can get the response back to the client?

**UPDATE:** To add more context, `body` returns the request, not any of the responses. I thought wrapping the `https.request` function in another function would help to capture the response, but it didn't work. I'm not familiar with Node so I know this needs I rewrite. I just want to know how I should rewrite it.

Comment: check this `require('dotenv').config` you need to call the config function: `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it and used the 'node-fetch' library instead of the 'https' one. It's a lot more elegant this way.

```sh
require('dotenv').config()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const querystring = require('querystring')

export default function(req, res){
    if (req.method === 'GET'){
        const url = new URL(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`)

        let data = process.env.NUXT_ENV_ZOOM_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.NUXT_ENV_ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET
        let newData = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')
        let b64string = newData.toString('base64')

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64string
            }
        }

        let zoomUrl = new URL('https://zoom.us/oauth/token')
        zoomUrl.searchParams.set('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
        zoomUrl.searchParams.set('code', url.searchParams.get('code'))
        zoomUrl.searchParams.set('redirect_uri', process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL)

        const getData = async options => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(zoomUrl, options)  
                const json = await response.json()
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                res.end(JSON.stringify(json))
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
            } 
        }

        getData(options)
    }
}
```

I'll still leave this up for anyone who can still answer the original question.